# Jogo da velha com minimax não funciona bom

Tags: c

Estou com algum problema no meu código no qual eu não consigo identificar. Em alguns momentos o meu minimax não faz a jogada correta na qual deveria impedir que o usuário vença. Já pesquisei tudo, mas não consigo. Segue o código em C:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int linha;
int coluna;

int max(int tabuleiro[3][3], int limite, int alfa, int beta);

void imprimir(int tabuleiro[3][3]){ //apenas imprime o tabuleiro
    int l;
    int c;
    for(l = 0 ; l < 3; l++){
        for(c = 0 ; c < 3; c++){
            if(tabuleiro[l][c] == 0){
                printf("    ");
            }else if(tabuleiro[l][c] == 1){
                printf("  X ");
            }else{
                printf("  O ");
            }
            if(c != 2){
                printf("|");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int verificar(int tabuleiro[3][3], int linha, int coluna){ // verifica se a linha e coluna estão ocupadas ou não
    if(tabuleiro[linha][coluna] == 0){
        return 1;
    }else{ 
        return -1;
    }
}

int checar(int tabuleiro[3][3], int limite){//verifica se alguém ganhou
    if((tabuleiro[0][0] == 1 && tabuleiro[0][1] == 1 && tabuleiro[0][2] == 1) ||
    (tabuleiro[1][0] == 1 && tabuleiro[1][1] == 1 && tabuleiro[1][2] == 1) ||
    (tabuleiro[2][0] == 1 && tabuleiro[2][1] == 1 && tabuleiro[2][2] == 1) ||
    (tabuleiro[0][0] == 1 && tabuleiro[1][0] == 1 && tabuleiro[2][0] == 1) ||
    (tabuleiro[0][1] == 1 && tabuleiro[1][1] == 1 && tabuleiro[2][1] == 1) ||
    (tabuleiro[0][2] == 1 && tabuleiro[1][2] == 1 && tabuleiro[2][2] == 1) ||
    (tabuleiro[0][0] == 1 && tabuleiro[1][1] == 1 && tabuleiro[2][2] == 1) ||
    (tabuleiro[0][2] == 1 && tabuleiro[1][1] == 1 && tabuleiro[2][0] == 1)){
        return 10;
    }else if((tabuleiro[0][0] == 2 && tabuleiro[0][1] == 2 && tabuleiro[0][2] == 2) ||
        (tabuleiro[1][0] == 2 && tabuleiro[1][1] == 2 && tabuleiro[1][2] == 2) ||
        (tabuleiro[2][0] == 2 && tabuleiro[2][1] == 2 && tabuleiro[2][2] == 2) ||
        (tabuleiro[0][0] == 2 && tabuleiro[1][0] == 2 && tabuleiro[2][0] == 2) ||
        (tabuleiro[0][1] == 2 && tabuleiro[1][1] == 2 && tabuleiro[2][1] == 2) ||
        (tabuleiro[0][2] == 2 && tabuleiro[1][2] == 2 && tabuleiro[2][2] == 2) ||
        (tabuleiro[0][0] == 2 && tabuleiro[1][1] == 2 && tabuleiro[2][2] == 2) ||
        (tabuleiro[0][2] == 2 && tabuleiro[1][1] == 2 && tabuleiro[2][0] == 2)){
            return -10;
    }else if(limite == 9){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}

int * guardar_posicoes(int *vetor, int i, int j, int tam){//preenche o vetor que será utilizado no min ou max com as posições que estão livres
    vetor[tam] = i;
    vetor[tam+1] = j;
    return vetor;       
}

int * casas_disponiveis(int matriz[3][3], int *vetor){//busca quais posições do tabuleiro estão livre
    int tam = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(matriz[i][j] == 0){
                guardar_posicoes(vetor, i, j, tam);//chamada do método para preencher o vetor
                tam = tam + 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return vetor;
}

int maior(int max, int alfa){
    if(max >= alfa){
        return max;
    }else{
        return alfa;
    }
}

int menor(int min, int beta){
    if(min <= beta){
        return min;
    }else{
        return beta;
    }
}

int min(int tabuleiro[3][3], int limite, int alfa, int beta){
    int l = limite;
    int valorMin;
    valorMin = checar(tabuleiro, l);
    if(valorMin != -1){
        return valorMin;
    }else{
        int vetor[20];
        for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
            vetor[k] = -1;
        }
        casas_disponiveis(tabuleiro, vetor);
        int i = 0;
        while(vetor[i] != -1){
            tabuleiro[vetor[i]][vetor[i+1]] = 2;
            l = l + 1;
            int valorMax;
            valorMax = max(tabuleiro, l, alfa, beta);
            if(valorMin > valorMax || valorMin == -1){
                valorMin = valorMax;
            }
            if(valorMin <= alfa){
                tabuleiro[vetor[i]][vetor[i+1]] = 0;
                return valorMin;
            }
            beta = menor(valorMin, beta);
            tabuleiro[vetor[i]][vetor[i+1]] = 0;
            l = l - 1;
            i = i + 2;
        }
        return valorMin; 
    }
}

int max(int tabuleiro[3][3], int limite, int alfa, int beta){
    int l = limite;
    int valorMax;
    valorMax = checar(tabuleiro, l);
    if(valorMax != -1){
        return valorMax;
    }else{
        int vetor[20];
        for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
            vetor[k] = -1;
        }
        casas_disponiveis(tabuleiro, vetor);
        int i = 0;
        while(vetor[i] != -1){
            tabuleiro[vetor[i]][vetor[i+1]] = 1;
            l = l + 1;
            int valorMin;
            valorMin = min(tabuleiro, l, alfa, beta);
            if(valorMin > valorMax || valorMax == -1){
                valorMax = valorMin;
                linha = vetor[i];
                coluna = vetor[i+1];
            }
            if(valorMax >= beta){
                linha = vetor[i]; 
                coluna = vetor[i+1];
                tabuleiro[vetor[i]][vetor[i+1]] = 0;
                return valorMax;
            }
            alfa = maior(valorMax, alfa);           
            tabuleiro[vetor[i]][vetor[i+1]] = 0;
            l = l - 1;
            i = i + 2;          
        }
        return valorMax;
    }
}

int main (void){
    int tabuleiro[3][3];
    int limite, opc, l, c, valor, alfa, beta;
    limite = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            tabuleiro[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    imprimir(tabuleiro);
    printf("Escolha um jogador para comecar:\n1 - Computador (X)\n2 - Usuario (O)\n");
    scanf("%d", &opc);
    if(opc == 2){
        printf("\nVez do usuario, informe as coordenadas\n");
        printf("Linha: ");
        scanf("%d", &l);
        printf("coluna: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
        tabuleiro[l][c] = 2;
        imprimir(tabuleiro);
        limite++;
        while(limite <= 9){
            if(limite%2 == 0){
                printf("\nVez do usuario:\n");
                printf("Linha: ");
                scanf("%d", &l);
                printf("coluna: ");
                scanf("%d", &c);
                int v = verificar(tabuleiro, l, c);
                if(v == 1){
                    tabuleiro[l][c] = 2;
                    imprimir(tabuleiro);
                    limite++;
                }else if(v == -1){
                    printf("\nEscolha outra opcao\n");
                }               
            }else{
                printf("\nVez do computador:\n");
                alfa = -20;
                beta = 20;
                max(tabuleiro, limite, alfa, beta);
                tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = 1;
                imprimir(tabuleiro);
                limite++;   
            }
            valor = checar(tabuleiro, limite);
            if(valor != -1){
                break;
            }
        }
    }else if(opc == 1){
        printf("\nVez do computador:\n");
        alfa = -20;
        beta = 20;
        max(tabuleiro, limite, alfa, beta);
        tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = 1;
        linha = -1;
        coluna = -1;
        imprimir(tabuleiro);
        limite++;
        while(limite <= 9){
            if(limite%2 == 0){
                printf("\nVez do computador:\n");
                alfa = -20;
                beta = 20;
                max(tabuleiro, limite, alfa, beta);
                tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = 1;
                imprimir(tabuleiro);
                limite++;
            }else{
                printf("\nVez do usuario:\n");
                printf("Linha: ");
                scanf("%d", &l);
                printf("coluna: ");
                scanf("%d", &c);
                int v = verificar(tabuleiro, l, c);
                if(v == 1){
                    tabuleiro[l][c] = 2;
                    imprimir(tabuleiro);
                    limite++;
                }else if(v == -1){
                    printf("\nEscolha outra opcao\n");
                }
            }
            valor = checar(tabuleiro, limite);
            if(valor != -1){
                break;
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("Opcao invalida, encerrando...");
    }
    if(valor == 10){
        printf("\n### Vitoria do computador! ###\n");
    }else if(valor == 0){
        printf("\n### Empate! ###\n");
    }else{
        printf("\n### Vitoria do usuario! ###\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Joguei normalmente. Tem como apontar uma situação em que o código desvirtue?

Comment: Você começa com o computador, aí escolhe as posições linha= 1 e coluna = 2, depois ele joga, na próxima você escolhe linha= 1 e coluna = 1, daí você vai observar que o computador não vai impedir o usuário.